# Magento | How can I prevent to go immediately to the shopping cart page once I have added an Item to it?

Tags: magento, addition, shopping-cart

I’m creating my first e-commerce website, and I'm using Magento to do it but I don't want to go directly on the shopping cart page after adding an item, How can I do it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's just a configuration setting.  `System -> Configuration -> Sales tab -> Checkout` and then `in the Shopping Cart tab you set the After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` to No. Easy! Good luck with the Big M :)